# Why react-native-reanimated-carousel does not allow manual swiping?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I am using `react-native-reanimated-carousel ^2.5.0` and it does show photos as it should but when I try to swipe left or right it does not do anything, it does not scroll nor shows any errors.

Here are dependencies related to it:

```
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.4.1",
"react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^2.5.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.4.2",
```

and here is the Carousel code:

```
<Carousel
  width={windowWidth * 1.1}
  data={newImgArr}
  windowSize={10}
  loop={true}
  mode={'parallax'}
  autoPlay={false}
  renderItem={({ item }, index) => {
     return (
        <FastImage
           source={{
              uri: item,
              priority: FastImage.priority.high,
              cache: FastImage.cacheControl.immutable,
           }}
           style={{ flex: 1 }}
           resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
        />
     );
  }}
/>
```

I would really appreciate some help here!

Comment: If you use the inspector to choose a visual element on the screen, is the carousel selectable or is there something over it? Shake device -> Show inspector

Comment: @Abe I cant detect if there is anything but it doesnt seem like. I click on the opened photo and it selects the photo frame so I guess there is nothing in front

Comment: @showtime which device are you using? I get manual swiping working on the web and iPhone, but not the android.

Comment: @dustydojo I use android

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This problem was already mentioned in a resolved [issue](https://github.com/dohooo/react-native-reanimated-carousel/issues/179).

You just have to wrap your Carousel in GestureHandlerRootView.

```js
export default function App() {
  return <GestureHandlerRootView>{/* content */}</GestureHandlerRootView>;
}
```

Comment: Now if I wrap this with Modal from the react-native-modal, it doesn't allow the modal to swipe down and close.

Comment: If someone encounter issue with not firing events or full blank screen, Try this out `<GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>`